# Function to find the quantile in a vector corresponding to constant $x$

Tags: r, quantiles, function

Suppose I have constant `x=0.1` in the language `R` and I have a vector `vec = rnorm(200)`. Is there a pre-packaged function to find the quantile of `vec` that corresponds the closest to `x`?

A solution is as follows:

```
x = 0.1
vec = rnorm(100)
percentiles = quantile(vec,seq(0,1,by=0.01))
which(abs(x-percentiles)==min(abs(x-percentiles))) 
#returns closest match
```

... but I would like to know if there's a pre-packaged function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is has no statistical content other than finding a function/specific R package. You can try http:/www.rseek.org 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, if had you bothered to read the manual of `quantile`, you would have found the function `ecdf` in the "See Also" section.

```
x <- 0.1
vec <- rnorm( 100 )
ecdf( vec )( x )
# or
my.ecdf <- ecdf( vec )
my.ecdf( x )
```

`ecdf` is a function returning another function -- that in turn is the experimental distribution function of your distribution.